# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dns'

Tags: python, python-3.x, email-validation

```
from email_validator import validate_email, EmailNotValidError

email = "example@gmail.com"

try:
  # Validate.
  valid = validate_email(email)

  # Update with the normalized form.
  email = valid.email
except EmailNotValidError as e:
  # email is not valid, exception message is human-readable
  print(str(e))
```

I am using this but I am getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dns'`.

Comment: Can you elaborate which package you are using?
And how did you install it? When using pip or similar, dependencies (I guess dnspython, but not sure) would have been installed automatically.

Comment: Can you try installing dnspython and try, probably a missing dependency (pip install dnspython)

Answer (score 2):

What probably happend is that you uninstalled the dnspython package after instaling the email-validator package.

The email-validator package needs the dnspython

Open a command line and input `pip install dnspython`, then restart your editor and that should do it.